# Generate the output in same spool in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-scripts

```
SPOOL c:\out.SPL

    SELECT * FROM a WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER='&CRN' ;
    SELECT * FROM b WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER='&CRN' ;

    Spool off
    accept op prompt 'Do u want to generate el spool,type y ' default 'n'
    SAVE c:\query2.SQL 
       select * from getm_liab   where liab_no='a' ;

    column c me new_value x
    set termout off
    select decode(lower('&op'),'y','C:\query2.SQL','n', 'null') c from dual;

    spool c:\out.SPL APPEND
    @&x
```

The above script is I run set of queries first and I will run remaining set of queries only when user types y.    But it is not working please suggest

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error but not getting what i wanted..The second set of queries is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

content of q1.sql:

```
accept op prompt 'Do u want to generate el spool,type y ' default 'n'

column c new_value x
set veri off
set echo off
set head off
spool qyn.sql
select decode(lower('&op'),'y','@','n', '--')||'q2'  from dual;
spool off

@qyn '&1'
```

content of q2.sql:

```
select 'boe' from dual where dummy = '&1';
select 'oops' from dual where dummy = '&1';
```

sqlplus foo/far@orcl @q1 X
output with Y:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 26 15:00:13 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2012, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Verbonden met:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Do u want to generate el spool,type y y

@q2


boe


oops
```

output with N:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 26 15:00:54 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2012, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Verbonden met:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Do u want to generate el spool,type y n

--q2
```

This is one of the ways to handle this. Easiest is to use the positional variables but you can also define them as named variables.